# Configure systemd-resolved to use local bind first and DHCP-provided DNS as fallback

Tags: dns, networkmanager, bind, systemd-resolved

I'm using Fedora 36 as my everyday desktop machine and I try to do something that I though was fairly simple but I can't find another person on the net providing a proper configuration for this.

Basically, everything is in the title: I want to find the proper `systemd-resolved` configuration to use my local Bind server as a DNS (nothing complex so far), *but also* fallback on any DHCP-provided DNS.

What I tried so far is to force `NetworkManager` to provide my local Bind instance in the DHCP-provided DNS in the first place with the following configuration:

```
# /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf
prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
require subnet-mask, domain-name-servers;
```

```
# /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/dhcp-client.conf
[main]
dhcp=dhclient
```

But that doesn't work. `systemd-resolved` still queries DHCP-provided DNS prior to my local Bind server.

I found a `systemd-resolved` configuration that queries my local Bind server:

```
# /etc/systemd/resolved.conf
DNS=127.0.0.1 ::1
Domains=~.
```

But I'm unsure that it falls back to DHCP-provided DNS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running your own name server, I actually suggest you disable `systemd-resolved` entirely (it's known to break with certain DNS features anyway, like DNSSEC).

```
systemctl disable systemd-resolved
systemctl stop systemd-resolved
systemctl mask systemd-resolved
```

Then you can control your resolv.conf file, or make it based on DHCP instead:

```
rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
ln -s /run/NetworkManager/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```